# Local variable vs private field effeciency

Tags: c#, variables, methods, scope

Is there like a rule of thumb about when to go either over the other?

Im curious because i have a dilemma here, where i have a very frequently used method, return a custom class type that is rather large. Im wondering if it wouldnt be cheaper to hold an instance of this custom class in a field, and then in the method just change and return it every time, rather than creating a whole new object as would be the case if i had a new class instance created in the method every time.

Comment: Yes, there is a rule, and it is very simple: when you need a local variable, use a local variable; when you need a field, use a field.

Comment: The two would functionally do different things, you need to first verify if the change in behavior is OK.

Comment: When you return an *instance* of a class (you can't return a class), you return its reference. The object will still be on the heap, regardless if it's a local variable or a field. And the choice between field and local variable is not a question of efficiency, but of functionality.

Comment: @K_Nielsen...  Return field(with class type)  wil be always faster than create new instance per every call. But do not forget if you return field, you return reference.

Comment: @Vasek that's a bold statement. Do you have any link to documentation where this is stated? What do you mean by your second statement "if you return field, you return reference"?

Comment: @Default I mean what `return _fieldOfTestClass;` wil be faster `return new TestClass();` "if you return field, you return reference" -  Return field of class type

Answer (score 1):

The main difference between returning a newly created instance of a class and returning a field is enormous: in the latter case, the instance is shared because all clients receive a pointer to the same instance. That means: whenever any of the clients (or the original creator of the instance) changes something in the instance, all clients will now see all those changes. In the former case, all instances are different, and changes affect only the current client.

So take a really close look at the requirements and find out which of the behaviors is required. Getting them wrong can have devastating effects.

Comment: first answer to address this critical issue, have an upvote!

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to ask for is a so called lazy field. You declare it as `System.Lazy<>` like so

```
private System.Lazy<YourClass> mYourClassInstance;

...

mYourClassInstance = new System.Lazy<YourClass>(() => new YourClass());
```

and then you can get the instance via

```
mYourClassInstance.Value
```

anywhere you want but the value (instance) is only created once.